# Foreign key constraint fails during `drop table`

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a strange problem in which I'm not able to delete a table as a foreign key constraint fails. The scenario is as follows.

I'm trying to `drop` the table `departments` from my DB, the structure for which is as follows:

```
show create table `departments`
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
     `dept_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `dept_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`dept_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now, the only other table in the database that has department_id is the `employee` table:

```
show create table employee
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
     `emp_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     `role` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `password` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
     `division_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `email_bb` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
     `date_joining` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `date_confirmation` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `date_appraisal` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `date_leaving` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `middle_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `sex` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `email_other` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `contact` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `present_addr` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `perma_addr` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As you can see, none of these tables are related via foreign keys. So why do I get this error when trying to `drop` the `department` table:

```
#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Is there a better way (and hopefully, simpler) way to see the foreign keys defined? What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*show create table* doesn't show incoming FK restraints (e.g. FK is specified in child table, not parent)

So there is a possibility that you have another table with a FK constraint to that table.  I usually dump the schema of the database, which shows all FK constraints.

Comment: You're right! There indeed was a another table referencing `dept_id`. I feel so ashamed. :'(

Comment: Happens to the best of us.  Glad you found it.